# bash: egrep & echo error at line

Tags: bash

how can I combine those two lines that if any TunerParams and or Calcinternal 
are found only "error: Rule 19: Tunerparams and/or Calicinternal in Script at line X, Y...." is echoed

```
{
egrep -E "TunerParams|CalcInternal" $INPUT_FILE -n | cut -d ":" -f 1
echo "error: Rule 19: Tunerparams and/or Calicinternal in Script at line"
}
```

Comment: can you show us sample data ?

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '/TunerParams|CalcInternal/ {print "error: Rule 19: Tunerparams and/or Calicinternal in Script at line", NR}' $FILENAME
```

Answer (score 2):

The `awk` solution from ocurran is a great one.  Since you seem interested in doing it with `egrep` in particular, you'd have to do it in a couple of steps:

```
line="$(egrep -E "TunerParams|CalcInternal" "$INPUT_FILE" -n | cut -d ":" -f 1)"
if [[ -z $line ]]; then
    printf 'error: Rule 19: Tunerparams and/or Calicinternal in Script at line %s\n' "$line"
fi
```

which will capture the output of the `egrep` command, then if there was anything in that output, will print the error message, otherwise it won't print anything